# LibTorch sizeof tensor

Tags: c++, libtorch

I would like to know how I can get the size in bytes of the data type of a `torch::Tensor`.
I saw somewhere online that `sizeof(tensor.dtype())` should work, but for my float32 tensor it prints out 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself finally.
`torch::elementSize()` returns the size of the given ScalarType.

To convert from `tensor.dtype()`, which has type `caffe2::MetaType`, to a Scalar, I had to use this converter `torch::typeMetaToScalarType(tensor.dtype())`

Therefore, the size of a tensor in memory can be calculated like this:
`tensor.numel() * torch::elementSize(torch::typeMetaToScalarType(tensor.dtype()))`

The docs mention none of those functions, making it very hard to find them.

Comment: in python this is something like:  t = torch.rand((1,10)); numbytes = t.numel()*t.element_size()